# Prevent CSV file downloading (CodeIgnitor)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to create csv and then send it to mail as attachment. I am using headers which is getting me downloaded the csv file. and if I remove the below then no CSV is created.

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
```

I dont want to download the file instead save it in some temp folder and then send it as attachment in mail.

below is what i did..

```
$this->load->library('excel');
    $filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'export') . '.csv';
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
  //$f = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $f = fopen($filename, 'w');
    $csv_header =  array("name","number","address"); 
    fputcsv($f, $csv_header);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    foreach ($data as $value) {
            $data_array = array($value['name'],$value['number'],$value['address']);
            fputcsv($f, $data_array);
            }
        }
    fclose($f);
```

Comment: So remove those `headers` then. The part of writing into a temp file you already got there, all you need to do now is send it as email attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Remove these header lines as they are used to download files to a browser.

```php
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
```

On the serverside, you should be good with just

```php
$this->load->library('excel');
$temporary_filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'export') . '.csv';
    
$file_write_stream = fopen($temporary_filename, 'w');
$csv_header =  array("name","number","address"); 
fputcsv($file_write_stream, $csv_header);
    
foreach ($data as $value) {
    fputcsv($file_write_stream, array($value['name'], $value['number'], $value['address']));
}

fclose($file_write_stream);
```

---

**Pro tips:**

1. Use meaningful variable names
2. For sending the email, I'd recommend using the [PHP mailer library](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). It makes sending email super simple and you can add an attachment with just one line. In your case:

```php
$mail->addAttachment($temporary_filename);
```